# unable to connect to redis with my celery project with rabbitmq as broker

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, celery

I am able to send the task to rabbitMQ and let my celery workers to execute the tasks but when i use the result URL with the task id, it just loads and does not show anything, I don't know if its due to connection error with Redis or what.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from celery import Celery
import time
app = Flask(__name__)

celery = Celery(app.name, broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0')

@celery.task    
def add_numbers(a, b):
    c=a+b
    time.sleep(10)
    return c

@app.route('/add/<a>/<b>')
def add(a,b):
    c=int(a)
    d=int(b)
    result = add_numbers.delay(c,d)
    #print("lol ",result)   
    return f'{result} xd Task ID: {result.task_id}'


@app.route('/result/<task_id>')
def result(task_id):
    
    task = add_numbers.AsyncResult(task_id)
    print(task.get())
    if task.state == 'SUCCESS':
        return f'Result: {task.get()}'
    else:
        return f'Task {task_id} is {task.state}'

    return "no such id"

    
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:-

```
celery = Celery(app.name, broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//', backend='redis://redis:6379/0')
```